# Resizing Lightbox 2 images

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox2

So I need lightbox 2 to have a maximum image width to resize images that are too large.

To do this I have adjusted the lightbox.css file to the following

```
#lightbox img {
  max-height:700px;
  max-width:700px;
}
```

This works in resizing the image itself, however the white Lightbox overlay remains the full size of the original image file so the image just kind of gets lost in the middle of the Lightbox. Any ideas? I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this:

```
.lb-outerContainer {
    max-width: 720px; 
    max-height: 720px;
}
.lb-dataContainer {
    max-width: 220px; /* For the text below image */
}
```

Comment: when I do this, the image is bigger than the box. The image seems to not rescale

Answer (score 3):

1) open slimbox2.js

2) rewrite this:

```
    w(h).css({ backgroundImage: "url(" + o + ")", visibility: "hidden", display: "" });
    w(q).width(l.width);
    w([q, I, d]).height(l.height);
```

to:

```
if (l.width > $(document).width() - 100) {
        l.height = l.height * ($(document).width() - 100) / l.width;
        l.width = $(document).width() - 100;
    }
    w(h).css({ backgroundImage: "url(" + o + ")", backgroundSize: "" + l.width + "px " +     l.height + "px", visibility: "hidden", display: "" });
    w(q).width(l.width);
    w([q, I, d]).height(l.height);
```

max width is

```
$(document).width() - 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the chosen answer means at a large size the images do not scale and overflow on the container. I found this solution to work in all cases for me.

```
.lightbox .lb-image {
  max-width: 712px;
  max-height: 712px;
 }
```

I added the max width and height to these classes instead, adjusting to pixels to account for the padding around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following to your CSS:

```
.lb-image{
    max-width: inherit;
}
```